# ngOptions Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following in the controller:

```
$scope.queoptions = [
{   name: 'que_1',
    type: 'Accidents'
},
{   name: 'que_2',
    type: 'Collect from store'
}
]
```

I would like to display:

```
<select>
   <option value="que_1">Accidents</option>
   <option value="que_2">Collect from store</option>
```

How do I use ngOptions correctly to do this.

Thanks

Comment: I found [this page very helpful](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/06/19/using-ngoptions-in-angularjs.aspx) when I started using `ngOptions` rather than `ngRepeat` on select option tags

Comment: I used
       <select ng-model="queselectedItem" ng-options="obj.name as obj.type for obj in queoptions">
            <option value="">Please select</option>       
      </select>

This produced

    <select ng-model="queselectedItem" ng-options="obj.name as obj.type for obj in queoptions" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
       <option value="" class="">Please select</option>
       <option value="0">Accidents</option>
       <option value="1">Collect from store</option>
    </select>

Still the incorrect option value.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from the comment what might be the matter, but your approach there appears correct.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eyPsn/1/).

```
<body ng-App="app" ng-controller="TestCtrl">

<select ng-model="queselectedItem" ng-options="obj.name as obj.type for obj in    queoptions">
<option value="">Please select</option>    
</select>

{{ queselectedItem }}    
</body>
```

"que_1" and "que_2" are selected as values when their respective option is chosen.

Comment: Thanks this seems to work and exactly what I am after.